# Recursively get children of parent id in array

Tags: php

I have this array

```
Array([23] => Array([21] => Array([1] => Array([] => Array()))))
```

I need to be

```
$result = array(23,32,1,0);
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: explain your question clearly

Comment: do you just need arrays key?

Comment: yes! sir you are right

Comment: function show_keys($ar)
      {
          $temp = array();
          foreach ($ar as $k => $v )
          {
              $temp[] = $k;
              if (is_array($ar[$k]))
              {
                  $temp = array_merge(show_keys ($ar[$k]), $temp);
              }
          }

          return $temp;
      }

Comment: Where does 32 come from?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$data=array(23=>array(21=>array(1=>array(''=>array()))));
// print_r($data);
$arr=array();
a:
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    if(is_array($data[$key])){
        $data=$data[$key];
        // continue;
    }

    if($key==''){
        $key=0; 
    }
    $arr[]=$key;
    goto a;

    // print_r($data);
}
print_r($arr);
?>
```